# DataBinding not working with lists

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm

I am working on a Windows Phone Application. I am binding a List to a content control element.

```
     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Width="100" Margin="163.558,67.567,192.441,453.612" Content="Click" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Strings , Converter={StaticResource Converter},ConverterParameter=0,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
    </Grid>
```

In the converter I am returning the string at the specified parameter.
My mainview model is as follows

```
      private List<string> strings;

    public List<string> Strings
    {
        get
        {
            return strings;
        }

        set
        {
            strings = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("Strings");
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Strings = new List<string>();           
    }

    private ICommand clickCommand;

    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            clickCommand = new RelayCommand(Click);

            return clickCommand;
        }
    }

    private void Click()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string abc = "This is string" + i.ToString();

            Strings.Add(abc);
        }
    }
```

I am expecting the content contorl to display 'This is string 0' , but it is showing **no strings** (I am returning this from the converter when the list is empty). This problem is not coming when I populate the list on startup i.e, add the items to the list in the view model's constructor. Why is this happening?

It is working fine if I bind the element rather than the list (**{Binding Strings[0]}**).

Answer (score 1):

You need use a `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` in order to make the view detect added and removed list items

Comment: Not working with ObservableCollection<T> also. The problem might be with binding the content control with a List<T> and then converting it . If I use Content = {Binding Strings[0]} it is showing the changes.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection triggers a CollectionChanged event when you add or remove item from the list.
List doesn't trigger event.

Your view (XAML) will never be awarded of changes, that's why you have to use ObservableCollection. as thumbmunkeys said.